# Android Studio Unable to start acitivity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

When I try to run the app, I get this error below, and I don't know what exactly is causing it.

Maybe there is some mistake with the project name, activity name, I don't really know what to do about that error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.homeactivity, PID: 5486
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.homeactivity/com.example.homeactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
    at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.getBottomNavigationItemViews(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:569)
    at com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx.setTextVisibility(BottomNavigationViewEx.java:244)
    at com.example.homeactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml if you want to take a look at it

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.homeactivity">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

also, here is my MainActivity.kt:

```
package com.example.homeactivity
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        bottom_navigation_view.setTextVisibility(false)
        bottom_navigation_view.enableItemShiftingMode(false)
        bottom_navigation_view.enableShiftingMode(false)
        bottom_navigation_view.enableAnimation(false)
        for (i in 0 until bottom_navigation_view.menu.size()){
            bottom_navigation_view.setIconTintList(i, null)
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my "app":

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.homeactivity"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
}
```

Comment: You got to give an id to the bottom_navigation and declare the bottom navigation in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, the error was in implementation:

```
implementation 'com.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
```

I just had to add "GitHub" xD

```
implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
```